# Can I put two 'if statements' in one function and how?

Tags: javascript, html

Can I put two `if` statements in `myFunction()` ?
How to add one more `'if'` statement to the `myFunction()` ?
Basically i need to set values for each specific checkbox, multiply it to number entered in the textbox and the result goes to 'total'.

For example :

```
if ( checkbox : Name - is selected) { 
    /*Multiply the value of Name*/ 200 * myNumber /*the number entered in textbox*/
}
```

And like before, the result goes to `total`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 0;
  $('label').click(function() {
    $('.option:checked').each(function() {
      $(this).parent().css('background', 'gold');
    });

    $('.option:not(:checked)').each(function() {
      $(this).parent().css('background', '#fff');
    });

    updateTotal();
  });
});

function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myNumber").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;

  if (x == 5 || x == 6 || x == 7) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 97 * x;

  } else if (x == 8 || x == 9 || x == 10) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 87 * x;

  } else if (x >= 11) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 82 * x
  } else {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 0;
  };

  updateTotal();
}

function updateTotal(){
    var total = 0;
    var totalAmount = 0;
    $('.option:checked').each(function() {
      total += parseInt($(this).val());
    });

    totalAmount = total + parseInt(document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML);

    $('#total').html( totalAmount +' $');
}
```

and

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" id="myNumber" onkeyup="myFunction()">
<p id="demo"></p>
<br>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="option" value="200" /> Name</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" class="option" value="300" /> Blah</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" class="option" value="400" /> XYZ</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" class="option" value="800" /> Something</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" class="option" value="1200" /> Item</label><br />
<br><br> Total :
<div id="total">0 $</div>
<br>
```

I am here for any further questions.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: "I am here for any further questions." good, because I have one: What is the question? I have no idea what you're trying to do.

Comment: What happens when you try? What problems do you encounter?

Comment: Yes, you can certainly have 2 or more `if` statements in a function.  But, I don't understand your question.

Comment: I'm sorry guys, i missed the question in the hurry . How can i add another 'if' statement in 'myFunction' ?

Comment: You can still edit your question..

Comment: What does _"How can i add another 'if' statement in 'myFunction'?"_ actual mean?? ... the sample you showed doesn't make sense in what you want to do. Maybe extend the explanation a little would be good.

Comment: @LGSon, i want to add one more 'if' statement to the myFunction() . How to do it ?

Comment: @SheldonCooper Don't really understand. You have 3 already, and you want, but don't how, how to add a 4th?

Comment: @LGSon,  Basically i need to set values for each specific checkbox, multiply it to number entered in the textbox and the result goes to 'total'. For example : if checkbox 'Name' is selected, multiply its value (200) to the number entered by the user.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you’re trying to achieve or not. But I’ll just walk you through simple usage of if, if else and else statements in your case.

In “myFuction” if you want a logic to be computed over the existing variables “x”, then you can go ahead and add another “else if” statement with the condition that you like to achieve.

But let say you want to add the logic around if for a whole new variable, let say “y”, then go on add another set of if, if else and else statement for y after the else block of “x”

Hope this helps. It would really help though if you can try to ask a precise question.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will try my best to make it work, because it's for very close friend of mine.

Comment: Sure. Let me know if you need any other help regarding the same

Comment: I try to make this : get the value of selected checkbox and multiply it to the entered number from the textbox. If myNumber is equal to 5 and checkbox Name (200) is selected, multiply them -> 200 * 5 = 1000.

Comment: First of all I think you need a radio button instead of check boxes. And in order to solve your problem, you don't need If statements at all. What you can do is set some value for each radio button (like you did for each checkbox above), then simply get the value entered by user  and the value of radio button selected by user, multiply them and display the result

Comment: I am new at this, i read, i try and mostly i fail :) Now i have some "progress" , i write : `var box1 = document.getElementById('VL05');` and `if (box1.checked){document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (7 * x) + document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;` and `<input type="checkbox" name="VL05" id="VL05" class="option" value="7" /> VL05</label><br />` . When i enter 5 in textbox i get 35485 instead of 520. So it merges the numbers instead of sum them (35+485). Where is my mistake ?

Comment: HTML data returned is in string format. So it is like '35' + '485' which gives '35485'. What you need to do id parseInt('35') + parseInt('485')

Comment: Ok, now i get 520 but its below textbox, not in 'total'. I have tried to change 'demo' to 'total' in order to calculate numbers in Total : . And when i check the 'VL05' checkbox i get number 7 again, not 35. It should be 485 in 'demo' and after checkbox 'VL05' to be 520 in 'total'.

Comment: I find my solution, it was so simple :D `if (box1.checked) {box1.value = x * 7;}` . Thanks to everyone that tried to help me. Have a nice day !